# Unity Dashboard does not search applications

Tags: 11.10, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity not searching applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65727/unity-not-searching-applications)

When i search for any application in the dashboard, it just returns files and folders matching my query. I have selected "Home" button (1st button) at the bottom. When i launch dashboard, i can see firefox icon in it but if i search for firefox, it returns nothing.

Comment: Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65727/unity-not-searching-applications/69498#69498